# Find first occurence (position) of number > 0 from end of string

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of an issue or maybe just tunnelvision: I want to get the first number from the end of an string which is *not* `0`. It is 100% safe that the given string consists just of numbers.

```
$number = 902200100;
$firstZero = strpos($number, "0");
preg_match('/[1-9]/', $n, $matches, PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL, -1);

var_dump($matches);

echo "first zero: " . $firstZero;
echo "\r\n";
echo "last non-zero: " . $matches[0][0];
```

Output is:

`first zero: 1` correct, the first zero is at position 2 [index 1].

`last non-zero: 0` is wrong, it should be 2 (position 3 from right, index 2).

I tried to change the flag to `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` as well, but that didn't do the trick. Is it possible, that the offset `-1` doesn't work here? What would be the correct approach then?

I also changed the pattern from [0-9] to [1-9], it feels like having 1-9 yields no output at all.

Sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2caa5051d73a91e6b19dd30187354b597638c68c

Comment: Hi, you are interpreting backwards, index0 = '9', index1 ='0', index2='2'

Comment: why is the last non-zero has to be 2 again?

Comment: @franzjoseph i mean, the index 2 (position 3). Depending on how you read it. It should be the position where the 1 occures

Comment: With the pattern `([0-9]*)[1-9]0`, you can get the index (from the **left**) thanks to the length of `$matches[1]`. You can get the index from the right from here.

Comment: `strrpos` not work? [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) - `Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string`  or `strrchr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex you could use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` as follow:

```
function maximizeNumberRoundness($n) {
    $firstZero = strpos($n, "0");
    preg_match('/([^0])0*$/', $n, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    echo "first zero: " . $firstZero;
    echo "\r\n";

    $last_nonzero_index = strlen($n) - $match[1][1] - 1;

    echo "last non-zero: " . $last_nonzero_index;
}

maximizeNumberRoundness(902200100);
```

Output:

```
first zero: 1
last non-zero: 2
```

This works as far as I understand correctly that you want the index of the last non-zero from the **right** of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Regex

```
preg_match('/([^0])0*$/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

In this case `902200100` output is

```
1
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/84b1bbc71172bcc9b5e0595c4567f8bddd9344cc)

Other choices

- strrpos - find the position of the right most occurrence eg. `$string[strpos($string,'0')];`

> Also, 1 isn't correct, since I need the position, not the value.

`strrpos` - note the `r` is like `strpos` but it finds the last occurance not the first

**UPDATE**

Try something like this, now that I think I understand what you want.

```
  var_export(preg_split('/(0)/', '902200100',-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => '9',
  1 => '0',
  2 => '22',
  3 => '0',
  4 => '0',
  5 => '1',
  6 => '0',
  7 => '0',
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45c30c0ea18b7f44d08661026c530005fc3532f1)

Then i would combine it with something like `array_itersect($split, [0])` etc.  Which would be

```
array (
  1 => '0',
  3 => '0',
  4 => '0',
  6 => '0',
  7 => '0',
)
```

In this case (note the keys), the rest is trivial.  If you want the position with single numbers, then just use `str_split`  and then intersect

Comment: But strpos can't have a regex-pattern as needle. I need to find any number except the 0. Also, 1 isn't correct, since I need the position, not the value. I should have made that more clear in my title, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just one possible solution:

```
$rev = strrev((string) $number);

$pos = function() use ($rev) {
  for($i=0;$i<count($rev);$i++) {
    if(rev[$i] != "0") return $i;
  }
};

echo "last non-zero": $pos();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. If you're going to call this function a lot, you should avoid using a regex.

```php
<?php

function getLastCharacterThatIsntZero($number) {
    $characters = array_reverse(str_split((string)$number));
    foreach($characters AS $character) {
        if($character != "0") {
            return (int)$character;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(getLastCharacterThatIsntZero(12345)); // returns 5
var_dump(getLastCharacterThatIsntZero(123450)); // returns 5
var_dump(getLastCharacterThatIsntZero(0)); // returns false
```